# JQuery .ajax() success always firing (even when server returns error code)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that is being serialized by JQuery and posted via .ajax() to a url.

The problem is that the 'success:' function is always called, regardless of whether the server returns an error code or not.

In fact, success fires even before the server has responded (I have put a breakpoint on the server method that services the request - success fires even before this method is completed).  If the server returns an error code (e.g. Status code 500) JQuery calls BOTH success and error events!

Any ideas what's going on? Here's my jquery code:

```
$("#a-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
    "Submit": function() {
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: theURL,
                  data: $("#a-dialog-form").serialize(),
                  success: alert('ok!') // THIS IS ALWAYS CALLED (IMMEDIATELY)
                });
        },
    },
});
```

**UPDATE:**

This was a stupid error on my part!  Thanks to blue112 for quickly pointing it out :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's normal, you must pass it as a callback, eg

```
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: theURL,
              data: $("#a-dialog-form").serialize(),
              success: function(){alert('ok!');} // The function will be called upon success.
            });
```

Comment: +1 - the OPs code is assigning the *return value* of `alert("ok!")` to the `success` property

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide success with a pointer to a function, or, as commonly used, by passing the function definition.

What you have to do is have something like this:

```
 "Submit": function() {
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: theURL,
                  data: $("#a-dialog-form").serialize(),
                  success: function (data) {
                          alert('ok!') // THIS IS ALWAYS CALLED (IMMEDIATELY)
                  }
                });
        },
    },
```

What's happening in your case is that the alert is called right away so you will see the alert message even if the ajax request didn't get fired at all.