# Jquery Insertions Lost after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple dialog widget which i am using to send some values to a server and add something to an unordered list too which displays on the page.
for e.g. name = matrixA a11=1 a12=2 a21=4 a22=1
so this data is passed to the server, and name attribute is to be appended to a list.

After user presses submit, a Validate() routine is called, which validates the entries, appends the name entry to an unordered list and submits the form.

However after the form is submitted the page is reloaded and the append is lost. Is there any way to avoid this? I know that the append worked as for a split second i can actually see it, but then the page reloads and we are back to beginning.

@EDIT : Heres a part of my code. The entire Code is become too big so please review this -

```
    <script>
    $('#form1').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //Validate is a function which returns a bool if validation proceeds correctly
        var isCorrect = Validate(this);
        if(isCorrect){
        //if validated correctly then submit, close widget, add name of matrix to a list

            this.submit();  
            $('#dialog').dialog('close'); //the form sits inside a dialog widget
            $('#selectable').append("<li class='ui-widget-content'>name</li>"); 
        } 

    });
    </script>
    <form name='form1' id='form1'  method='get'>
<fieldset>
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input type='text' name='nameofmatrix' id='Name' class='whitepanes'><br>
    <label for="a11">a11</label>
    <input type="text" name='a11' id='a11' class='whitepanes number-field'><br>
    <label for="a22">a22</label>
    <input type="text" name='a22' id='a22' class='whitepanes number-field'><br>
    <label for="a12">a12</label>
    <input type="text" name='a12' id='a12' class='whitepanes number-field'><br>
    <label for="a21">a21</label>
    <input type="text" name='a21' id='a21' class='whitepanes number-field'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='mysubmit' id='submit_button'  value='submit'>
    <button id='cancel_button'>cancel</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: put some code to see or better to post a [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: You could use ajax to prevent page reload by form submission.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915827/combining-jquery-validation-followed-by-ajax-post/7916448#7916448

Comment: do NOT submit the form in the submit event and for sure not if you want to stay on the page. Instead use $.post

Answer (score 0):

You may need to share your code.

But what I would do is put a click listener on your submit button.  And then use prevent default to stop the page from reloading.

e.g.

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); //important
  // calculations here
  // validate method

});
```

Or as  `mplungjan` mentioned you can use the `submit` event on your `form` instead.

```
$('#formID').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); //important
  // calculations here
  // validate method

});
```

Comment: using the form submit event is better in my opinion!

Comment: Hey Trevor, shared some code(which i should have done in first place but for some laziness). I am already doing something similar to what you posted. Problem being, once you submit after validation, page reloads and the list insertion that i did is gone after validating.

Comment: Oh so you do need to submit the form.  Rather then `this.submit();` you can do a `ajax` call to submit your form using the ajax call back you won't have to reload your page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105236/jquery-ajax-success-always-firing-even-when-server-returns-error-code helpful link on ajax calls.

Comment: @new_web_programmer please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question.  Otherwise give feedback on what is not working.  Thanks.